# How to use 2 different versions of the same node dependency in package.json?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui, package.json

I am working on a react js application where I am using [Material-UI v5.0.0](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.0.0-rc.0) for my UI components.
This new version replaces the package names from @material-ui/* prefix with @mui/*:

```
@material-ui/system -> @mui/system
@material-ui/styles -> @mui/styles
@material-ui/lab -> @mui/lab
```

In my project I am also using another dependency for displaying a calendar on 1 page which has a peer dependency of [Material-UI v4.12.3](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v4.12.3) which imports material libraries like `@material-ui/system`.

How should I manage my dependencies in package.json so that I can use Material-UI v5.0.0 for majority of my UI/UX and still be able to use the dependency just for a specific UI screen.

Should I npm install both material UI v5.0.0 and v4.12.3 or is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [npm](https://npmjs.com) or [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) you may install specific packages under aliased names enabling you to use the same package under two different versions to do so you may

```sh
npm install <alias>@npm:<pkg_name><@version> # for npm
yarn add <alias>@npm:<pkg_name><@version> # for yarn
```

Example:

Installing Material-UI

```
npm install v5n@npm:@mui/material@5.0.0
npm install v4n@npm:@mui/material@4.12.3
```

Then you may require them as

```js
import Button from 'v5/Button';
```

Comment: Since all the dependencies of v5.0.0 are imported as 

import Button from "@mui/material/Button"
and the dependecies of v4.12.3 are imported as 
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

do i need to use alias ?

Comment: Absolutely! if you alias it you need to `import/require` it as alias itself!